# PHP to Publish something on some wall?

Tags: php, facebook, drupal

I have a Drupal blog. Every time I create a blog entry, I want to use actions and some php code to post to both my fan page and my personal wall, something like: New blog post. Check it out at bla bla bla.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems relevant :

http://drupal.org/project/simple_fbwall

Comment: This doesn't QUITE do what I want. It allows anyone to post on whatever I configure. So I basically need the code that this model uses to post, so I will investigate it a bit.

Comment: You can use the hook_menu_alter function to alter the menu path from where you do the post on the drupal site and override the user access to a specific role.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Wall and Fan pages can syndicate RSS feed content. While you could use a specific Face Book integration module, you can also use any RSS feed your site generates, including custom RSS feeds defined with the Views module, to define what will appear in Facebook.

With this approach you need to configure Facebook to pull in feeds from specific URLs, instead of configuring Drupal to speak to your Facebook account.

Comment: Not the route I want to go, but your comment made me sit for about 30 minutes thinking about this. :-p